# Why are there two variants of the implementation of CRCs in software

Tags: crc

I'm digging into the subtleties of CRCs. If I understand correctly, every CRC polynomial is provided in at least two representations, the normal one and the reversed one.

The normal one targets implementations where the content is processed from most signifiant bit to least significant bit and switched to the left (like for example in [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks)).

The reversed one aims to handle LSb to MSb interfaces. If you process LSb to MSb with the reversed polynomial and switching to the right you get the same CRC value (also encoded LSb to MSb). This is described for example [here](http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html). This is convenient for LSb to MSb communication interfaces.

What I don't understand is when you switch to software implementations. Why are there two variants of a software ie. byte implementation? (One for MSb to LSb, and one for the opposite bit order.)

Answer (score 0):

You do not get the "same CRC value" (reflected or not) with the reflected calculation. It is an entirely different value, because the bits of the message are processed in the opposite order.

*"when you switch"*: You simply use the CRC definition, reflected or not, that matches what the application is expecting. Whether the CRC is reflected is one of several parameters that define the CRC, along with the number of the bits in the CRC, the polynomial, the initial value, and the final exclusive or value. You can find the definition of *over a hundred* different CRCs [here](https://reveng.sourceforge.io/crc-catalogue/all.htm).

*"why are there two"*: The forward implementation exists because that corresponds most closely to the mathematics, with the least significant term of the polynomial in the least significant bit of the binary representation of the polynomial. The reflected implementation exists because it was realized that it could be implemented in software a little more simply, with fewer instructions, but still have the same error-detection performance.

Here is an example for two common 32-bit CRCs with the same polynomial. Forward, CRC-32/BZIP bit-wise implementation:

```
uint32_t crc32bzip2_bit(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= (uint32_t)data[i] << 24;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 0x80000000 ? (crc << 1) ^ 0x4c11db7 : crc << 1;
        }
    }
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

Reflected CRC-32/ZIP bit-wise:

```
uint32_t crc32iso_hdlc_bit(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc = ~crc;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc ^= data[i];
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xedb88320 : crc >> 1;
        }
    }
    crc = ~crc;
    return crc;
}
```

The main savings is one instruction, the shift up of the data byte, that you can get rid of with the reflected implementation. Also the constant that you `&` with (`1` vs. `0x80000000`) is smaller, which may also save an instruction or a register, or perhaps just result in a shorter instruction, depending on the size of immediate values supported in the instruction set.

The shift is avoided for byte-wise calculations as well:

```
uint32_t crc32bzip2_byte(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc = (crc << 8) ^
              table_byte[((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

vs.

```
uint32_t crc32iso_hdlc_byte(uint32_t crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ data[i]) & 0xff];
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: For those implementations, the inversions were folded into the tables.

Comment: Yes, you're correct for `0x80000000` with a 32-bit word, you could just use sign-bit conditionals. (You meant `&`, not `^`.) I was referring to the more general case, where the bit being examined does not happen to be the high bit of the register, such as using 64-bit registers for a 32-bit CRC, or for 16-bit or 8-bit CRCs, etc.

Comment: I deleted my prior comments. I don't understand why the bit-wise versions are complementing the users initial CRC value. I haven't seen this done before. In the byte-wise left shifting CRC for `((crc >> 24) ^ data[i]) & 0xff`, why is there a `& 0xff` ?

Comment: The initial `crc = ~crc;` is part of that particular CRC definition. In general, it would be `crc ^= exor;` before the loop and `crc ^= exor;` after the loop, where `exor` is the final exclusive-or for that CRC. The starting value of `crc`, i.e. the CRC of an empty sequence, is `init ^ exor`, where `init` is the initial value of the register from the definition.

Comment: The `& 0xff` is redundant in this particular case, since the number of bits in the CRC happens to be the same as the number of bits in the type. In general however, the `& 0xff` protects against being fed an invalid `crc` value, which could result in an out-of-bounds access of the table.

Comment: "You do not get the "same CRC value" (reflected or not) with the reflected calculation" I don't understand. All articles I've found mention that the reflected polynom is used for LSbit to MSbit communication interfaces. For example from wikipedia Ethernet Frame page : "An alternative is to calculate a CRC using the right shifting CRC32 (poly = 0xEDB88320, initial CRC = 0xFFFFFFFF, CRC is post complemented, verify value = 0x2144DF1C), which will result in a CRC that is a bit reversal of the FCS"

Comment: Sorry but it's still not very clear. You seem to imply that both implementation lead to the same result and the second one is just slightly faster. So function `crc32bzip2_byte`and `crc32iso_hdlc_byte` return the same CRC ?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean Those don't return the same CRC as each other. They return the same CRC as their `_bit` counterparts.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean The only difference between the two CRCs in my answer is that one is reflected. On the ASCII message `123456789`, the non-reflected CRC gives `0xfc891918`, and the reflected CRC gives `0xcbf43926`. Those are _not_ reflections of each other.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean The wikipedia page you reference is flipping _two_ things. It says that if you use a forward CRC, but flip the _data_ (processing it least significant bit first), you will get the same thing as a reflected CRC where you _don't_ flip the data. Which is correct.